# C# - Linq - XPathSelectElement returns the same results everytimes

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a problem with XPathSelectElement while reading some xml-lines....

the function handleEachSession is called two times from the mathod childList.ForEach() from my other function:

```
private void handleMonitorResponse(XElement receivedSessions)
 {
 List<XElement> childList = receivedSessions.Elements().ToList();
 childList.ForEach(handleEachSession);
```

childList has two elements (two XML lines, those i want it to have)
Then i can see in the Debugger that both calls of handleEachSession() gets the right XElement session. Those two i want it to have.

Now there are these XPathSelectElement's. It works for the first call but not for the second.
Second time i get the new XElement session, but XPathSelectElement still Returns the old values from the first call.
Hum!?? I cant understand this behavior.

```
private void handleEachSession(XElement session)
 {
 XElement receivedSessionId = session.XPathSelectElement("//sessionId");
 XElement receivedQuality = session.XPathSelectElement("//quality");
 XElement receivedContentStatus = session.XPathSelectElement("//contentStatus");
…
```

Can anyone please help me?

The XMLs are:

```
receivedSessions = 
<sessions type="array">
  <item type="object">
    <sessionId type="string">8c86716a87</sessionId>
    <quality type="string">mid</quality>
    <addressUri type="string">http://192.168.6.234/media/SorrowPinkFloyd_.mp4</addressUri>
    <currentTime type="number">1.5542887</currentTime>
    <contentStatus type="string">paused</contentStatus>
  </item>
  <item type="object">
    <sessionId type="string">c795067c4e</sessionId>
    <quality type="string">mid</quality>
    <addressUri type="string">http://192.168.6.234/media/trailer.mp4</addressUri>
    <currentTime type="number">3.3492105</currentTime>
    <contentStatus type="string">playing</contentStatus>
  </item>
</sessions>

session = (first call)
<item type="object">
  <sessionId type="string">8c86716a87</sessionId>
  <quality type="string">mid</quality>
  <addressUri type="string">http://192.168.6.234/media/SorrowPinkFloyd_.mp4</addressUri>
  <currentTime type="number">1.5542887</currentTime>
  <contentStatus type="string">paused</contentStatus>
</item>

session = (second call)
<item type="object">
  <sessionId type="string">c795067c4e</sessionId>
  <quality type="string">mid</quality>
  <addressUri type="string">http://192.168.6.234/media/trailer.mp4</addressUri>
  <currentTime type="number">3.3492105</currentTime>
  <contentStatus type="string">playing</contentStatus>
</item>
```

Comment: Please include the XML (a sufficient, but short, fragment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to the [xpath-syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), the double slash (//) means: Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are.
so with that in mind, you probably have to change your `handleEachSession` function as

```
private void handleEachSession(XElement session)
{
    XElement receivedSessionId = session.XPathSelectElement("sessionId");
    XElement receivedQuality = session.XPathSelectElement("quality");
    XElement receivedContentStatus = session.XPathSelectElement("contentStatus");
}
```